How to schedule monthly email to send include records from that month
I have a spreadsheet with a table that keeps records of my receipts

this is the data collected for each record: date, amount, store, and purpose.

I like to do the following:

on the first of the month, PowerApp will automatically run this script
the script will go into a spreadsheet to take all the records of the previous month
the script will copy and paste the data into an email
the script will tally the total amount from all the records of the previous month

Is this doable? Can I use PowerApps to do it? If not, can someone point me in the right direction?



on the first of the month, PowerApps will automatically run this script


Yes, doable. Scheduled Flow will be used for this


the script will go into a spreadsheet to take all the records of the previous month.


Yes, doable. With flow condition for reading records of previous month.


the script will copy and paste the data into an email


Yes doable, HTML table can be insert in email body.


the script will tally the total amount from all the records of the previous month


If you mean to get sum of the amount from previous months record then yes doable.
